# How to do on page load of dynamic pages with JavaScript and Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up an on page load function for dynamic pages (shows) that will only display certain variables that meet the requirements. For example if someone clicks on West Coast the map will only display California, Washington, and Idaho. If they click on Great Plains the map shows Iowa, Nebraska, Kansas. And so on.

Right now I have it set up, in my region.js file:

```
app.regions = () => {
   function init() {
    startGoogleMap();
    }

 let startGoogleMap = () => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("region-banner"), {
        zoom: 7,
        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        gestureHandling: "cooperative",
        styles: mapStyle
    });

  const cali = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
    map: map,
    icon: '/icon.jpg',
    title: 'California',
    region: 'West Coast'
   });

 return init();
 };
```

Then in my regions I actually have a list of regions with the following in the table:

```
create_table "regions", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
 t.string "url_name"
end
```

So in a nutshell I need to compare a variable against the region name on page load.

UPDATE:
This is what is currently in my show:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="banner" id="region-banner">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.regions);</script>
```

EDIT:
I applied the following in my show > script:

```
let regionContainer = document.getElementById('region-banner');
regionContainer.dataset.region
```

Then changed my show to:

```
<div class="banner" id"region-banner"><%= @region.name %></div>
```

Nothing happened. No errors though.

Comment: The reason nothing changed in the script, is that you actually need to set and save the value. You should add the `data-region="<%= @region.name %>"` attribute to the *region-banner* div. And use the value by first saving it to a variable: `let regionName = regionContainer.dataset.region` and use that to set the correct region in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix for future reference I did with both JS and Rails.

In JS

```
const markers = {
  "west/coast": [{
    position: [x,y],
    title: 'California'
  }]};
app.regions = () => {
function init () {
  startGoogleMap();
  }
let startGoogleMap = () => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("region-banner"), {
        zoom: 3,
        minZoom: 3,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        gestureHandling: "cooperative",
        styles: mapStyle
    });
    var mapElement = document.getElementById("region-banner");
    const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name')
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    markers[regionName].forEach(({ position, ...opts }) => {
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            ...opts,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(...position),
            map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });
```

Then in the show:

```
<div class="banner" id="region-banner" data-region-name=<%=@region.name.downcase%></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use data attributes on the container in which your map is loaded (although you could really use any element).

Assuming you have a variable `@region` for the current region in your show view, and assuming you're going to load the map in a div with a "map" id, you could do something like this in the markup:

```
<div id="map" data-region="<%= @region.name %>"></div>
```

And then you could retrieve that attribute in your JS file with something like this:

```
var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map');
mapContainer.dataset.region // Would be the result of @region.name
```

Comment: I updated the code. I'm actually pulling it with <div id="region-banner"></div>.

Comment: Or alternatively `<%= tag.div(id: 'map', data: {region: @region.name}) %>`